# Could not find :couchbase-lite-android-1.4.1 - ionic android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I am trying to build the android project developed using ionic framework. Once after the project build successful message it is trying to download the gradle plugin details specific android 
 platform with the following lines.

Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
.....................................................................................
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

after all download I am getting the below mentioned error

Please help if anyone faced the same issue.
Thanks in advance.

I have tried removing android platform and adding it back still getting the same error

BUILD FAILED in 21s
14 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 10 up-to-date
/Users/arunkumarb/SVN Repo/Inter/Working/Code/inter Mobile/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find :couchbase-lite-android-1.4.1:.
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     file:/Users/harshakumar/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository//couchbase-lite-android-1.4.1//couchbase-lite-android-1.4.1-.pom
  >     file:/Users/harshakumar/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1-.aar
  >     file:/Users/harshakumar/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1-.pom
  >     file:/Users/harshakumar/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1-.aar
  >     https://maven.google.com//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1-.pom
  >     https://maven.google.com//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1-.aar
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1-.pom
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1-.aar
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1-.pom
  >     https://repo1.maven.org/maven2//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1//couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1-.aar
  >     file:/Volumes/Arun 2/Users/arunkumarb/SVN Repo/Inter/Working/Code/Inter Mobile/platforms/android/app/libs/couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1-.aar
  >     file:/Volumes/Arun 2/Users/arunkumarb/SVN Repo/Inter/Working/Code/Inflyte Mobile/platforms/android/app/libs/couchbase-lite-android-sqlite-custom-1.4.1.aar
  >   Required by:
  >     project :app
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
cordova build android exited with exit code 1.
Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.

Comment: Any reason you are using 1.4.1 version of couchbase lite? That's End-of-Life(EoL) and superseded by 2.x version.

Answer (score 0):

I is issue of `cordova` downgrade it

```
 npm install -g cordova@8.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried installing cordova 8.0.0 but still facing the same issue.

Comment: remove platform and add it again